# Junit Assert - Converting two Java objects to XML and make assertions about them as XML

Tags: junit, marshalling, assert

I have to write a Junit test where I have to compare two XML documents . Initially both these documents are Java Objects. I'm not sure how to convert them to XML and compare them?

This is the code I have so far:

```
Actual RsActual = exchange.getIn().getBody(Actual.class);
ExpectedRs expectedRs = new ExpectedRs();
String newRs=FileUtils.getFileContent("src/test/resources/Test/ExpectedRs.xml");
expectedRs.setXYZField(newRs.toString());
Assert.assertEquals(expectedRs.getXYZField(), RsActual.getXYZField());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different possible solutions here. The most obvious is to get an XML mapper to convert each of your objects to XML documents as Strings and then do a simple equality assertion.

This is an example using Jackson's XmlMapper type:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
final String expectedString = mapper.writeValueAsString(expectedRs);
final String actualString = mapper.writeValueAsString(RsActual);
assertThat(actualString, equalTo(expectedString));
```

This will only work if your two types `Actual` and `ExpectedRs` produce exactly the same XML.

You could, alternatively, use the xml mapper to convert your expected document into an object and use the object's `equals()` method to compare the two things:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
ExpectedRs expectedRs = mapper.readValue(newRs, ExpectedRs.class);
assertThat(RsActual, equalTo(expectedRs));
```

You can also use simplify assertions about XML documents stored as String's using a library called [xmlUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/)